# Why does the focus on input block the ability to update value in the input?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to implement the fucntionality of restoring the previous input value (the correct value) when onBlur patch request returns an error. Everything works correctly as long as the input does not have focus on it. I've tried setting the value in several ways, like by input ref, changing the useState value (which should do re-render), keeping the previous value, etc. I'm almost sure the problem is in the focus on the input. Why is the focus blocking the ability to change? I'll add that after leaving focus on input, the value is set to the correct one.

```
import { NumberInput } from "@mantine/core";
import { usePrevious } from "@mantine/hooks";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

export const TableNumberInput = ({
  cell,
  mutate,
}: {
  cell: unknown;
  mutate: unknown;
}) => {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const [value, setValue] = useState<number | "">(parseFloat(cell.getValue()));

  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(parseFloat(cell.getValue()));
    // inputRef.current.value = value
    // inputRef.current.focus();
    // inputRef.current.select();
  }, [error]);

  const handleChange = (val: number) => {
    setValue(val);
  };

  return (
    <NumberInput
      ref={inputRef}
      value={value}
      error={error}
      precision={2}
      onChange={(val) => handleChange(eval(val))}
      parser={(value) => value.replace(/\$\s?|(,*)/g, "")}
      onBlur={(event) => {
        setError("");

        const num = eval(event.target.value);
        const rounded_num = Math.round(num * 100) / 100;

        if (value != parseFloat(cell.getValue())) {
          mutate(
            {
              id: cell.row.original.id.toString(),
              data: { [cell.column.id]: rounded_num },
            },
            {
              onError: (err) => {
                // inputRef.current.focus();
                // inputRef.current.select();
                setError("Incorrect value");
                // setValue(parseFloat(cell.getValue()));
              },
            }
          );
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};
```